# Significance of the ORIGIN Parameter of Workbooks.Open Method?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

In the [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) the following is stated:

> If the file is a text file, this argument indicates where it
> originated, so that code pages and Carriage Return/Line Feed (CR/LF)
> can be mapped correctly. Can be one of the following XlPlatform
> constants: xlMacintosh, xlWindows, or xlMSDOS. If this argument is
> omitted, the current operating system is used.

When I try to open a text file that originated in a Windows PC but I use the enumeration value 1, that is Macintosh (see [enum values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlplatform)) it opens correctly. Should this be the case given that a wrong origin has been mentioned? I understand that this is an optional parameter but i would like to understand when to use this parameter...can someone pls help?The command used was:

```
oxl.Workbooks.Open("G:\Excel Experiments\mytestData.txt",,, ,,,, 1)
```

Comment: My understanding is that this is antiquated, where `xlMacintosh` & `xlWindows` are in agreement, despite being on separate OS, though the use for `xlMSDOS` would still be of importance.  It should be a matter of compatibility for the file(s).

Comment: @Cyril thanks for the comments. I saved an empty excel file as TEXT (MS-DOS). When opening it programmatically, I deliberately supplied the wrong parameter (1 - macintosh). Again the file opned correctly. Seems like even the requirement for `xlMSDOS` is antiquated. Do you think i am correct?

Comment: I believe you would be correct.  In the modern age, the programs have been designed to be compatible; for some older items (I'm thinking back to WinNT and Mac OS 7), you may have to specify.  I guess that even nowadays, the MSDOS information is compatible (I hadn't tried it, but I'm glad you did!), due to the changes in programming.  The essential point I'm getting at is that the designation was of importance at one time, and for using computers/OS of that age, these may still be important... but are seen as antiquated, currently.